# What characters need to be escaped in .NET Regex?

Tags: .net, regex, escaping

In a .NET [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) pattern, what special characters need to be escaped in order to be used literally?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I don't know the complete set of characters - but I wouldn't rely on the knowledge anyway, and I wouldn't put it into code. Instead, I would use [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) whenever I wanted some literal text that I wasn't sure about:

```
// Don't actually do this to check containment... it's just a little example.
public bool RegexContains(string haystack, string needle)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("^.*" + Regex.Escape(needle) + ".*$");
    return regex.IsMatch(haystack);
}
```

Comment: Escape $ character too?: `var needle = @"any text here$%# more text";`

Comment: @JonSkeet: thanks for pointing out Regex.Escape, I was about to re-invent a square wheel till i saw your answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet : I know it is late, but why not to do it to containment? I have to use .net 1.1, so I can't use String.Contains, and equivalents

Comment: @rodrigocl: use `haystack.IndexOf(needle) >= 0`

Comment: interesting that this escapes spaces, which seems to work OK

Comment: Also, interestingly, this does NOT escape "-" (hyphen), which causes issues in character classes. I guess convention is to place hyphen first in a character class so most people won't have issues like I did with what ended up being a string like this: 
$@"[a-zA-Z0-9{System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape("_-$}")}]" 
which caused a somewhat confusing "parsing "[a-zA-Z0-9_-$]" - [x-y] range in reverse order." ArgumentException.

Comment: I agree with not putting this knowledge in code. However, I find myself writing regex as input for .NET tooling from time to time and knowing what chars to escape can be very helpful in that situation.

Comment: @csrowell - You should read the documentation that Jon linked to: "*Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, `*`, `+`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `[`, `(`, `)`, `^`, `$`, `.`, `#`, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. This instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters literally rather than as metacharacters.*" You cannot use `Escape` to escape the contents of a character class... that is not what the function is designed to do.

Comment: `Regex.Escape` doesn't escape a monkey sign @

Comment: @MladenB.: Why would it? What special meaning do you expect `@` to have in a regex?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I believe it has to do with named parameters.

Comment: @MladenB.: Not that I'm aware of. Unless you can give a concrete example of a case where it needs escaping, I'm afraid I think you're mistaken. (Named parameters in *SQL* use @ in many databases, but that's entirely different to regular expressions.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, I was testing regex with Azure Search and noticed when @ was not escaped, the regex didn't work properly. Could be Azure Search issue as well, but looking into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#escaping-special-characters I don't see @ as a special char which needs escapng...

Comment: @MladenB.: You linked to "Lucene query syntax", which isn't the same as ".NET Regular Expression syntax". I wouldn't be at all surprised for them to be different.

Comment: @JonSkeet, that's understood, of course. What I'm trying to say is that @ is not a special character in the Lucene world, so I assumed there is a special meaning in the Regex domain. I think the best thing to do would be for me to try to come up with a small test, to confirm @ is relevant to Regex escaping or not.

Answer (score 31):

Here is the list of characters that need to be escaped to use them as normal literals:

1. Opening square bracket `[`
2. Backslash `\`
3. Caret `^`
4. Dollar sign `$`
5. Period or dot `.`
6. Vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`
7. Question mark `?`
8. Asterisk or star `*`
9. Plus sign `+`
10. Opening round bracket `(` and the closing round bracket `)`
11. Opening curly bracket `{`
12. Pound/Hash sign `#`

These special characters are often called "metacharacters".

But, I agree with Jon to use `Regex.Escape` instead of hardcoding these character in code.

Comment: I think you need to include the `{` in your list.

Comment: and include `"`

Comment: As JDB said, it depends on context.  For example, `]` is not on the list but needs to be escaped if used as a literal and preceded by `[`.

Comment: I get an error if I try to escape asterisk or star * but seems to be working if I don't escape it.

Comment: Why do you need to escape the octothorpe ('#') symbol? That appears to be an error in the above list.

Comment: @knockNrod use can use `#` to [add a comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#miscellaneous-constructs) to the regex. Plus Regex.Escape also thinks it should be escaped - good enough for me 

Answer (score 14):

See the MSDN documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#character_escapes

The problem with a complete list is that it depends on context. For example `.` must be escaped, unless it is enclosed in brackets, as in `[.]`. `]` technically does not need to be escaped, unless it is preceded by `[`. `-` has no special meaning, unless it's inside of brackets, as in `[A-Z]`. `=` has no special meaning unless it is preceded by `?` as in `(?=)`.

Answer (score 14):

I think you can get the list of chars as

```
List<char> chars = Enumerable.Range(0,65535)
                .Where(i=>((char)i).ToString()!=Regex.Escape(((char)i).ToString()))
                .Select(i=>(char)i)
                .ToList();
```

--

```
\t\n\f\r#$()*+.?[\^{|
```