# counting a string with special characters in a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, counting

I would like to count a string (search term) in another string (logfile).
Splitting the string with the method Split and searching the array afterwards is too inefficient for me, because the logfile is very large.

[In the net](http://sstut.com/csharpdotnet/count-strings-in-another-string.php) I found the following possibility, which worked quite well so far. However,

```
count = Regex.Matches(_editor.Text, txtLookFor.Text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
```

I am now running into another problem there, that I get the following error when I count a string in the format of "Nachricht erhalten (".

Errormessage:

> System.ArgumentException: "Nachricht erhalten (" analysed - not enough )-characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `(` symbol as it has a special [function](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in regular expressions:

```
var test = Regex.Matches("Nachricht erhalten (3)", @"Nachricht erhalten \(", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
```

If you do this by user input where the user is not familiar with regular expressions you probably easier off using `IndexOf` in a `while` loop, where you keep using the new index found in the last loop. Which might also be a bit better on performance than a regular expression. Example:

```
var test = "This is a test";
var searchFor = "is";
var count = 0;
var index = test.IndexOf(searchFor, 0);
while (index != -1)
{
    ++count;
    index = test.IndexOf(searchFor, index + searchFor.Length);
}
```

Comment: Are there any other characters, i need to escape? Like ***" - . >*** ?

Comment: @Soeren3003 See : [What characters need to be escaped in .NET Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963165/what-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-net-regex) , you can simply use Regex.Escape

Comment: `if  you do this by user input` -> be careful, one shouldn't execute arbitrary regular expression without caution (use a timeout or instance). It's not just for simplicity to the user, it can also be a vulnerability (Deny of service, see [https://www.meziantou.net/regex-deny-of-service-redos.htm] and search for "catastrophic backtracking"

Comment: Thanks for the information and the source code. I have compared both once and come to the following result: ***00.0396874 sec*** While and ***00.0039259 sec*** Regex. Nevertheless, i have decided to use the while loop, because the performance is sufficient for my application.

Comment: @Soeren3003 true. It depends a bit on the context. The regex is fast for a few occurances, but for larger files with many occurances it'll become significantly slower due to the resulting allocations (which also quickly chews up memory).